# Restoring dependencies in Visual Studio Code is using the wrong source/feed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, nuget-package-restore

I'm not sure how to set the default nuget feed for my .net core project in Visual Studio Code to https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

When I attempt to add a package (and subsequently, restore dependencies), I get the following errors...

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.403\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://smartassessor.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/SANuget/nuget/v3/index.json. [c:\Users\Matthew.OConnor\Desktop\Important Documents\Programming\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\DatingApp.API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.403\NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [c:\Users\Matthew.OConnor\Desktop\Important Documents\Programming\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\DatingApp.API.csproj]
```

This source `https://smartassessor.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/SANuget/nuget/v3/index.json` has nothing to do with my current project, however it is used for other projects that are typically run using full blown Visual Studio. Those projects are saved in a completely different place to this project.

I simply want to be able to add nuget packages from nuget.org in my .net core project. How do I do this in VS code?

I don't currently have a **nuget.config** file in this project.

The package source mentioned in the error appears to be coming from a package source I have setup whilst using Visual Studio

[image]

This is my **csproj** file...

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.1.4"/>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="4.0.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="CloudinaryDotNet" Version="1.3.1"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

`CloudinaryDotNet` is the package that generated the errors above.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think VS Code is just running a `dotnet restore`, and the reason you're seeing this source being used is because it's configured in your User/Computer nuget configuration file (located on windows, which you seem to be running, at `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` & `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\NuGet\Config` respectively). The VS configuration editor you showed is just a nice GUI for this configuration file.

If you want to keep this general setting, you should be able to use a `nuget.config` file in your VS Code project (which you mentioned you don't have at the moment). There is more info on this here -[Add custom package source to Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358490/add-custom-package-source-to-visual-studio-code).

Also, if you're trying to restore manually, you can use one of these 2 flags -

- `dotnet restore --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`
- `dotnet restore --ignore-failed-sources`

These are pretty self explanatory, but you can see the full documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore?tabs=netcore2x

Hope this helps (:

Comment: Awesome, you made my day. Thanks