# custom nuget package source instead of nuget.org in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, nuget

I am trying use visual studio code for .net project development and i want to set the custom package source pointing to the artifact location of ADO. Could you please let know how it can be acheived in visual studio code

Did try
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source
[Add custom package source to Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358490/add-custom-package-source-to-visual-studio-code)

expecting :

Nuget package source to be customized (pointing to my ADO artifact location)

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to do it in vs code, but did you try to do it on visual studio and then load it in vs code?

Comment: Did you tried nuget vscode [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager) and add package source commands. What exactly you tried?

Comment: I am trying change the package source in vs code